# Keeping multiple values in an index of JavaScript Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, associative-array

I would like to keep values like below

```
var skus = [];    
<?php
    foreach($col as $Product)
        {
            ?>
                <script type="text/javascript"> 
                    skus['<?php echo $Product->id; ?>'] = '<?php echo $Product->sku; ?>','<?php echo $Product->color; ?>';
                </script>
            <?php
        }
    ?>
```

But this is not working.

**UPDATE**

Later I would like to search values of the array **skus** using that index.Is it possible in JavaScript like below??

```
var my_array = [];
my_arry['abc'] = 'pqr','xyz';
```

Is it possible to store multiple values in an index of an array in JavaScript??
Thanks

Comment: "But its not working" is not a good description. You should explain what exactly is going wrong

Comment: Set var skus = new array(); before the loop begins

Comment: I am not getting the second value of an index of the array. Thanks.

Comment: I'd recommend making `skus` an object instead of an array, since the product id might not start from 0 and be in a sequence.

Comment: @bub `var skus = new Array();` and `var skus = []` essentially are very different, the one you suggested being worse then the one in the OP's question, try to avoid object wrappers when possible.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the problem with your code is a typo in the JS. I assume you want to make an array out of the PHP values in JS, so it looks like all you're missing is the square brackets around your value list.

Like so: 
`skus['<?php echo $Product->id; ?>'] = ['<?php echo $Product->sku; ?>','<?php echo $Product->color; ?>'];`

Answer (score 0):

You can use some objects:

So:

```
skus['<?php echo $Product->id; ?>'] = {'sku':'<?php echo $Product->sku; ?>','color':'<?php echo $Product->color; ?>'};
```

So every element of the skus array is an object with two keys

Comment: generally better to use an array, when the structure is simple, for performance sake

Comment: How can I find an index in **skus** array which has a matching values of **sku** and **color**?? Thanks

Comment: for(var i = 0, len = skus.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (skus[i].sku === searchSku) {
        index = i;
        break;
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

My PHP is a little rusty but is this what you mean?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var skus = [];
    <?php foreach($col as $Product) { ?>
        skus['<?php echo $Product->id; ?>'] = ['<?php echo $Product->sku; ?>','<?php echo $Product->color; ?>'];
    <?php } ?>
</script>
```

You need [] on that middle line because you're trying to save two values into each "cell" of the array, right?

Comment: Yes, your are right. But I am getting another array after **=**. I have two values which I have to search/match in **sku** and **color** . Then I have to pick the index(**id**) from the array. How can I do that??

Comment: so you have `$Product->sku` and `$Product->color` and want to find `$Product->id`? You could create an object lookup like so `var skus = {}; skus['<?php echo $Product->sku; ?>-<?php echo $Product->color; ?>'] = '<?php echo $Product->id; ?>';`